# Does Shor's algorithm work for noncommutitive or nonassociative algebras?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quaternions, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

Shor's algorithm is said to solve the hidden subgroup problem for finite Abelian groups, at least according to the Wikipedia article I read. This means that it can be used to solve factoring or discrete logarithm problems for integers. Can Shor's algorithm be used to factor non-commutative or non-associative unique factorization domains such as Hurwitz quaternions or 'Cayley integers' described by Conway and Smith over octonions? Does the hidden subgroup problem for finite Abelian groups not apply to these algebras because they aren't finite Abelian groups?

Comment: Comment rather than answer because it's little more than a Wikipedia link, but: no efficient quantum HSP algorithm is known for non-abelian groups, and such an algorithm would imply efficient quantum algorithms for graph isomorphism; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_subgroup_problem.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I don't understand the HSP well enough to know if the HSP for finite abelian groups is referring to some morphism or to the algebra it's operating in directly. Post quantum crypto seems to focus on entirely different algorithms like shortest vector, coding theory or hidden field equations rather than just using discrete log or factoring trapdoors in different algebras, and I wondered why.